# Javascript removing Event and adding Event

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events

I try to disable an `onclick` event and bring it back. Disable it works fine with:

```
 <div id="rob_icon_gui" onclick="robbery()"</div>

function bye() {
document.getElementById("rob_icon_gui").onclick = '';
}
```

but it doesn't come back:

```
 <div id="rob_icon_gui" onclick="robbery()"</div>

function hallo() {
document.getElementById("rob_icon_gui").onclick = 'robbery()';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `document.getElementById("rob_icon_gui").onclick = 'robbery()';` to

`document.getElementById("rob_icon_gui").onclick = robbery;`

```js
function robbery() {
  console.log('Executing Robbery')
}

document.getElementById("rob_icon_gui").onclick = robbery;
```

```html
<button id='rob_icon_gui'>Click</button>
```

Comment: Other way is to use `.addEventListener('click', robbery)` and `.removeEventListener('click')`

Answer (score 1):

Your html

```
<div id="rob_icon_gui clickablediv"</div>
```

You script

```
var handler = function() {
  alert( "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog." );
};
```

You can bind your click event like this

```
$('.clickablediv').bind('click',handler);
```

and you can unbind click event as well

```
$('.clickablediv').unbind('click',handler);
```